# Java: Read and Output file contents into byte format

Tags: java

I posted here earlier today on a similar question and I'm aware that I'm not supposed to ask HW questions on here.  My question IS for homework but its already been finished and submitted (and graded), I'm just here to hopefully get my program running with a better understanding:)

To show that I've already completed it and not trying to pull a fast one, here's a link to the submission page: http://i959.photobucket.com/albums/ae76/GoWxGaiA/SOHW2pic_zps25eb2d2a.jpg

The instructions are right here: http://i959.photobucket.com/albums/ae76/GoWxGaiA/pic3_zpsbb6c6541.png

Here is what I had so far and submitted:

```
package Homework1;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    public class HW1 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("Enter a file name:                         c:/users/logan/desktop/untitled.png");
        System.out.println("Byte#     Byte\n0:        255\n1:        216\n2:        255\n3:        244\n4:        0\n5:        16\n6:        74\n7:        70\n8:        73");      
   File file = new File("C://Users//Logan//Desktop//Untitled.png");   
   try
        {
          FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);     
          byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];

   fin.read(fileContent);
   String strFileContent = new String(fileContent);     
   System.out.println("File content : ");
   System.out.println(strFileContent);
     }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)    {
  System.out.println("File not found" + e);    }
catch(IOException ioe)    {
  System.out.println("Exception while reading the file " + ioe);    }
  }
}
```

So my questions are:

**Question 1:** How do I prompt the user to enter a filename instead of just hard-coding one?

**Question 2:** How do I use a loop to display each individual byte value?

All and any help is greatly valued!

Comment: you can hand the file name in as an argument `args` this will give you some flexability you need, if the argument is null throw an exception. 

    byte[] byteArr =  myString.getBytes();
     for (byte b : byteArr)
    {
      // sys out b 
    }

Comment: Ok, let me try it out real quick.

Answer (score 1):

To prompt some one for input consider using the Scanner class

```
System.out.print("Please enter file path and name: ");
String input = scan.nextLine();
```

to loop around byte-by-byte `inputStream.read()` method
see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()

```
while ((ch = fis.read ()) != -1) {
   System.out.print(ch);
}
```

Comment: The link is very useful!  Thx friend!